# Investment taxes after I move abroad

Tags: taxes, greece

I lived in the Netherlands for some years, now I am back to my home country Greece.
While living in the Netherlands I’ve made some investments,  not being a tax resident in Greece.
No returns made from these investments yet.
Now that I am living to Greece once again, when the time comes to take profits, what should I do? I can declare the profit from investment here, BUT how did I buy in the first place if I didn’t have any income in Greece at the time?

Not sure if I’m clear, thanks in advance!

Comment: The country where you are resident for tax purposes can usually tax your total worldwide income, earned or unearned https://europa.eu/youreurope/citizens/work/taxes/income-taxes-abroad/index_en.htm You might be best to talk to a tax adviser in Greece.